# How to apply single SQL OR operator to a table and its associated tables in Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I want to to find products with a certain sub string in it (Searching for products) i.e., where the search string matches `product.name` OR `product.description` OR { in an associated table (`category.name` OR `category.description`) } OR { in other associated (hasMany) table ( `sku.description`)  i.e, if anywhere in all the SKU's description}

I have a tables with following structure

`products`  with fields `id | name | description | categoryId` 
`categories`  with fields `id | name | description`
`sku`  with fields `id | productId | description`

with relations

```
db.product.belongsTo(db.category);
db.category.hasMany(db.product);

db.sku.belongsTo(db.product);
db.product.hasMany(db.sku);
```

ultimately I want products where search string matches anywhere for a product.

```
db.product.findAll({
   include: [
      {
         // hasOne relation
         model: db.category,
      },
      {
         // hasMany relation
         model: db.sku,
      },
   ],
   where: {
      [Op.or]: [
         {
            name: {
               [Op.like]: `%${search}%`
            }
         },
         {
            description: {
               [Op.like]: `%${search}%`
            }
         },
         // this doesn't work need some way to achieve something like this
         // {
         //    category:{
         //       name: {
         //          [Op.like]: `%${search}%`
         //       }
         //       description: {
         //          [Op.like]: `%${search}%`
         //       }
         //    }
         // }

      ]
   }
})
```

I can apply the `where` condition inside the `include` section of `category` but that won't work like an overall OR like what I need for Search.

this won't give expected results

```
   include: [
      {
         model: db.category,
         where : {
            name: {
                [Op.like]: `%${search}%`
            }
            description: {
                [Op.like]: `%${search}%`
            }
         }
      }
   ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clauses using joined table columns that don't work out of the box can be wrapped in $.

To obtain top-level WHERE clauses that involve nested columns, Sequelize provides a way to reference nested columns: the '$nested.column$' syntax.

It can be used, for example, to move the where conditions from an included model from the ON condition to a top-level WHERE clause.

```
User.findAll({
  where: {
    '$Instruments.size$': { [Op.ne]: 'small' }
  },
  include: [{
    model: Tool,
    as: 'Instruments'
  }]
});
```

Generated in SQL:

```
SELECT
  `user`.`id`,
  `user`.`name`,
  `Instruments`.`id` AS `Instruments.id`,
  `Instruments`.`name` AS `Instruments.name`,
  `Instruments`.`size` AS `Instruments.size`,
  `Instruments`.`userId` AS `Instruments.userId`
FROM `users` AS `user`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `tools` AS `Instruments` ON
  `user`.`id` = `Instruments`.`userId`
WHERE `Instruments`.`size` != 'small';
```

for documentation you can read it here:
https://sequelize.org/master/manual/eager-loading.html

Comment: It worked. However there were some issues regarding sub query which I resolved. if the above solution doesn't work - try adding `required` to your included model. also if the included model has `hasMany` relationship (like product -> sku in the question) sequelize will make nested queries which may make sku.property unavailable inside the nested query. So to avoid this add a property `subQuery : false` to your root query (`db.product.findAll({  subQuery : false }`) to avoid nested queries.

Comment: but that also means that the offset and limit is applied on each row (like for every sku and not product) so that will alter your pagination stuff which is intended to be applied for individual products.